# How to resolve memory overloading by passing an iterator to CountVectorizer?

Tags: scikit-learn, nlp

I'm working on extracting text features from a large dataset of documents (about 15 million documents) using `CountVectorizer`. I also looked at `HashingVectorizer` as an alternative, but I think `CountVectorizer` is what I need, as it provides more information about text features and other stuff.

The problem here is kinda common: I don't have enough memory when fitting the `CountVectorizer` model.

```
def getTexts():
    # an iterator that will yield each document from the database

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(max_features=500, ngram_range=(1,3))
X = vectorizer.fit_transform(getTexts())
```

Here, let's say I have an iterator that will yield one document at a time from a database. If I pass this iterator as a parameter to `CountVectorizer` `fit()` function, how is the vocabulary built? Does it wait until finishing loading all the documents and then do the `fit()` once, or does it load one document at a time, do the fit, and then load the next one? What's a possible solution to resolve the memory overhead here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why `CountVectorizer` will consume much more memory is that the `CountVectorizer` needs to store a vocabulary dictionary in memory, however, the `HashingVectorizer` has a better memory performance because it does not need to store the vocabulary dictionary. The main difference between these two vectorizers is mentioned in the [Doc](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.HashingVectorizer.html) of `HashingVectorizer`:

> This strategy has several advantages:
>
> - it is very low memory scalable to large datasets as there is no need to store a vocabulary dictionary in memory
> - it is fast to pickle and un-pickle as it holds no state besides the constructor parameters
> - it can be used in a streaming (partial fit) or parallel pipeline as there is no state computed during fit.
>
> There are also a couple of cons (vs using a CountVectorizer with an
>   in-memory vocabulary):
>
> - there is no way to compute the inverse transform (from feature indices to string feature names) which can be a problem when trying to
>     introspect which features are most important to a model.
> - there can be collisions: distinct tokens can be mapped to the same feature index. However in practice this is rarely an issue if
>     n_features is large enough (e.g. 2 ** 18 for text classification
>     problems).
> - no IDF weighting as this would render the transformer stateful.

And of course the `CountVectorizer` will load one document at a time, do the fit, and then load the next one. In this process the `CountVectorizer` will build its vocabulary dictionary as the memory usage surging.

To optimize the memory, you may need to reduce the size of document dataset, or giving a lower `max_features` parameter may also help. However if you want to resolve this memory problem completely, try to use the `HashingVectorizer` instead of the `CountVectorizer`.